# Server Error PHP when attempting to access database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, internal-server-error, bluehost

How do I elucidate this error message? I've spent a few hours on this already.
Basically when I connect to myapp.mysite.org I get it to work, the same with myapp.mysite.org/docu and the other pages, but when I need to query the database, I get this cryptic "Server Error" thing. Any tips on how I go about starting this, I am at wit's end. How can I at least have some sort of error logging so I see where things are failing.

Hosted on Bluehost, Code Igniter app.

config/database.php

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['test']['username'] = 'me_name';
$db['test']['password'] = 'me_password';
$db['test']['database'] = 'me_database';
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['test']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['test']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['test']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['test']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['test']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess

```
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Logs end at DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Database Driver Class Initialized

Comment: First step: check your error logs.

Comment: And what's your cryptic server error thing ? Be precise.

Comment: Re error: on Chrome it basically says "Server Error". Turned on the error logging. Logs stopped at DEBUG - 2012-10-05 23:55:41 --> Database Driver Class Initialized. So I'm currently checking out the possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->db);
echo "</pre>";
```

run the above code to check your db's details, seems ur htaccess file is fine
ane make sure your `$active_group` in is the right one.